# How to close a wallet without stopping the RPC server?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, rpc, monero-wallet-rpc

I am trying to use RPC to perform such actions as:

1. Check balance and make transfers using selected wallet
2. The needed wallet should be unlocked just before any tranfer and locked immediately after

monero-wallet-rpc (with --wallet-dir option) can do the first part, but I have some problems with the second.

When I start monero-wallet-rpc, no wallet is loaded and I should manually do that using "open_wallet" function with filename and password parameters. After that, I can request balance ("getbalance") or transfer ("transfer") funds, none of them needs password anymore. I tried to close wallet using "stop_wallet" command to "lock" the wallet, but it stops the entire monero-wallet-rpc daemon (so I can't anymore open wallets without restarting monero-wallet-rpc).

The only solution that I found to solve the problem is to use "open_wallet" on some temporary wallet, so that it replaces the "battle" one, but I am not sure, that "battle" wallet is fully closed and the whole solution doesn't seem to be correct.

What else can I do to achieve listed requirements? May be there are some other tools (or options) that can be used?

Answer (score 2):

Recent monero code has a close_wallet RPC, as seen in https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4007.

This call will close the currently opened wallet, if any, if you've started monero-wallet-rpc with --wallet-dir.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, using a dummy/empty/temp wallet as you described is the only option via the wallet RPC. Furthermore, `open_wallet` does indeed close any previously opened wallet.

Answer (score 0):

As [@user36303](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/22/user36303) mentioned, in version 0.13.0.x a "close_wallet" command appeared. So it is now possible to open wallet with "open_wallet" command, sync it with "refresh" command (it can take some time), store updated state with "store", perform activities and close with "close_wallet".